# Battery powered RGB matrix board

Tags: raspberry-pi, battery-operated, led-matrix

I'm not sure if this is the best place to ask this but I'm not sure where else too

For my graduation I'm trying to embed a Led RGB matrix display connected to a raspberry pi on my cap. Iv seen this done before but I'm trying to figure out the best way to power it.

The documentation says the board needs 5v/4a for full power. The connector is just +- bare wires and I was originally going to splice this onto a USB cable to be powered by a backup battery pack.
(Like the kind you would charge an iPad with) 
 This is the way I have seen it done before as well but the best battery I can find are max 5v/2.4 amps on a single port with 5v/4.8a total. 
I'm not sure how others have made it work, maybe by using both ports simultaneously or maybe just by not using all the LED on the board at a time. 
The raspberry pi is easy to power but the led Matrix it's self is the problem.

Specifically what I'm using is this led board
https://www.adafruit.com/product/1484
With this as the control board
https://www.adafruit.com/product/2345?gclid=CjwKEAjw3KDIBRCz0KvZlJ7k4TgSJABDqOK7cI7D7wwQngD1iQS12nLYY6kadgxEOYFFARfDUHfPChoC4_Dw_wcB

I would be grateful if anyone has any suggestions for me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest picking up a decent lithium battery meant for RC applications. They're cheap, and readily available. Chargers are also fairly easy to get too. If you decide to invest in something decent you can keep using it for future projects.

It's fairly straightforward to calculate how long the battery will last. It'll depend on what voltage battery you get though. Say you get a 3s LiPo battery with 1Ah of capacity, it has a nominal voltage of 11.1V. At full load of 4A draw the converter will draw just under 2A from the battery. A 2A draw from a 1Ah battery gives you 0.5 hours of run time.

You'll need to add in overhead for the efficiency of the converter, and also to avoid discharging the battery too deeply. Ideally you want to keep the battery above 20%.

Digikey and other suppliers have plenty of compact easy to use DC DC converter modules which can power the LED controller from the battery.

[Standalone DC DC Converters](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/power-supplies-external-internal-off-board/dc-dc-converters/132?FV=ffe00084%2C15c0002%2C11800066%2C11800069%2C11800070%2C11800487%2C11800075%2C11800492%2C11800078%2C118004cb%2C118004da%2C118004dc%2C118004de%2C1180007d%2C1180053f%2C1180057b%2C11800591%2C118006a5%2C118006a8%2C118006c7%2C118006df%2C118006e2%2C118006ff%2C118000ba%2C118000c3%2C118000cd%2C118000cf%2C11800818%2C11800819%2C1180081f%2C11800821%2C11800822%2C1180082a%2C1180082c%2C11800837%2C1180083f%2C11800841%2C118000d4%2C11800855%2C1180087a%2C1180088d%2C118000db%2C11800890%2C118008a4%2C118008a9%2C118008f5%2C118000e6%2C118000f2%2C118000f4%2C118000f7%2C118000fd%2C118009e3%2C118009fa%2C11800100%2C11800102%2C11800105%2C11800a3d%2C11800a73%2C11800a74%2C11800a75%2C11800a76%2C11800a77%2C11800a78%2C11800a79%2C11800a7a%2C11800a7b%2C11800a7c%2C11800a7d%2C11800a7e%2C11800a7f%2C11800a80%2C11800a81%2C11800a82%2C11800a85%2C11800a86%2C11800a87%2C11800a89%2C11800a8a%2C11800a8b%2C11800a8c%2C11800a8d%2C11800a8e%2C11800a8f%2C11800a90%2C11800a91%2C11800a92%2C11800a94%2C11800a95%2C11800a96%2C11800a97%2C11800112%2C11800114%2C11800118%2C11800122%2C11800125%2C11800126%2C11800128%2C1180012d%2C11800131%2C11800143%2C1180014a%2C1180014d%2C11800151%2C11800156%2C1180016e%2C11800185%2C118001a5%2C118001a6%2C118001a9%2C118001aa%2C1180002b%2C1180002c%2C118001cb%2C118001e6%2C118001ea%2C11800230%2C1180003a%2C1180003b%2C11800251%2C11800261%2C1180003d%2C11800276%2C11800042%2C118002b3%2C1180004a%2C1180004f%2C11800058%2C11800061%2C17d4003e&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=1000011&page=1&stock=1&pbfree=0&rohs=0&quantity=&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=500)

[Board Mountable DC DC Converters](https://www.digikey.com/short/3nm3c2)

Don't forget these converters are pretty efficient, but they're not magical. Make sure there's adequate cooling available or you might burn your head. All of that is specified in the data sheet, so you can get an idea of what to expect.